# Golang API + Android: cannot access API on Android

Tags: android, api, go, post, request

I developed a Golang API to communicate with my Android app. My API is located on my "server" (currently an old laptop) and I can access my API on my Android device when both are connected on the same network, use the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the manifest and use the IP (192.168.X.XX:XXX) of my server on my Android app. Cool so far :)

But now I want to access using different networks, for this, I created a Dynu account with DDNS with a built-in domain (test.freeddns.org). On my Android log displays:

> No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

So I tried using network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">test.freeddns.org</domain>
    </domain-config> 
</network-security-config>
```

but it gives me the following message:

> 2022-11-10 12:08:53.518 30659-30745 NetworkSecurityConfig D  Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true

I tried using the public IP of my server with no success :( I still get the same error

I use the
`RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);` on my Android App to send a POST request to my server.

Any ideas will be more than welcome

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: sooooo quick update ... as mentioned before, I have Dynu setup with DDNS with port forwarding so whenever I type test.freedns.org my destination will be http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:port. The exception I am getting on Android is:
 error: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX not permitted

Comment: Hi everyone ... so everything is cleared up ! its all good. i managed to solve my problem. tks for all the help